# partitioning suggestions for new SSD in old Macbook Pro

Tags: partitioning, macbook-pro

I jus got a new 1TB SSD for my old (late 2011) Macbook Pro. I was going to pop it in tomorrow and then remembered I will now have the oh-so-fun task of reinstalling/configuring OS X and applications (mostly Adobe Creative Suite and a handful or 2 of dev/IDE apps and utilities). I currently have it configured as purchased used... 3 partitions - 1 for OS, 1 for apps and 1 for data/storage. Organizational benefits aside, is there any advantage to splitting it up like that since it's all 1 physical disk? By that, I mean will Photoshop perform better running on a partition separate from the OS? or if something disastrous happens to the OS, will storing my files on a separate partition make their recovery more likely?

Any preferred/standard/recommended/favorite configs welcome for half designer, half developer, quarter internet addict, zero gamer welcomed. Thanks!!

Comment: You can clone your drive with [Disk Utility](https://youtu.be/lfJrAcnHN2g) if you want to avoid having to install everything again.

Answer (score 0):

Run macOS High Sierra (the latest release that still supports your ancient 2010 MBP) on it and format it as a single APFS container with as many volumes (inside the container)  as you want. All volumes in an APFS container share the same free space. APFS is designed for SSDs so it does things right. Just go APFS and don't sweat the details.